Location of Casper source files
I have Ubuntu 24.04 and installed the Casper source file package.
Which directory can I find the C source files?

What package, exactly - and how did you install it? Source packages installed via apt go into the current directory by default.

You say you installed it, but aren't clear as to which package you installed; if you installed a binary package using apt install then there is no source package. Did you use a source install?  and where its located relates to $PWD or your present working directory ..  ie. if I cd ~/blah then apt source casper I'd look for the package sound in ~/blah/

You say you installed it, but aren't clear as to which package you installed; if you installed a binary package using apt install then there is no source package.
Did you use a source install?
Also note where its located relates to $PWD or your present working directory ..  ie. if I cd ~/blah then apt source casper I'd look for the package sound in ~/blah/
guiverc@d7050-next:~$   cd blah
guiverc@d7050-next:~/blah$   apt source casper
NOTICE: 'casper' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
https://git.launchpad.net/casper
Please use:
git clone https://git.launchpad.net/casper
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 109 kB of source archives.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu plucky/main casper 1.502 (dsc) [1,741 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu plucky/main casper 1.502 (tar) [107 kB]
Fetched 109 kB in 2s (58.6 kB/s) 
dpkg-source: info: extracting casper in casper-1.502
dpkg-source: info: unpacking casper_1.502.tar.xz
Notice: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.alt_sources' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
guiverc@d7050-next:~/blah$   ls
casper-1.502      casper_1.502.tar.xz  ubuntu-wallpapers-24.04.2                ubuntu-wallpapers_24.04.2.dsc
casper_1.502.dsc  pinxi                ubuntu-wallpapers_24.04.2.debian.tar.xz  ubuntu-wallpapers_24.04.2.orig.tar.gz
guiverc@d7050-next:~/blah$   cd casper-1.502/
guiverc@d7050-next:~/blah/casper-1.502$   ls -lah
total 64K
drwxrwxr-x 9 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Jul 17 03:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Nov  3 08:27 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Mar 31  2024 bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guiverc guiverc  437 Jul 16 08:52 casper.conf
drwxrwxr-x 2 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Jul 17 03:28 casper-md5check
drwxrwxr-x 2 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Mar 31  2024 caspermon
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guiverc guiverc  18K Mar 31  2024 COPYING
drwxrwxr-x 5 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Sep 14 04:17 debian
drwxrwxr-x 2 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Mar 31  2024 hooks
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guiverc guiverc  406 Mar 31  2024 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 4 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Mar 31  2024 scripts
drwxrwxr-x 2 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Mar 31  2024 ubiquity-hooks

